# FBWF on Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC

Tags: windows-10

Is there any possibility to run FBWF on Windows 10 or is the driver model no longer compatible? Some quick trials blue screened, but we might not be doing it right.

Also, UWF is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: By FBWF you might mean "File Based Write Filter". Please give more information about the context and what you are trying to do.

Comment: A bounty is useless if the question is formulated in a way nobody understands what you are asking. You should edit it and add more details.

Comment: @Robert Not sure what else to write. I'm simply wondering if it is possible at all to run FBWF on Windows 10, or if the driver model has changed making it impossible. I also figured that using the abbreviation FBWF would be ok since anyone not familiar with it would also most likely not be familiar with the file based write filter itself...

Comment: Using only abbreviations is one point. There are always more than one resolution for an abbreviation often even in a specific context. Furthermore you don't write what exactly you are trying to achieve. May be you are just not aware that there is alternative? I would strongly recommend to read other good voted questions to learn how to write a good question. A good question usually does not require any bounty.